# ASP.NET MVC with custom actionresult: outputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I want to generate a PDF and I'm using the following code in my controller to call it:

```
public PdfActionResult Index()
{
   return new PdfActionResult("");
}
```

the custom actionresult 'pdfActionResult' looks like this:

```
 public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var _pdfConverter = new PdfConverter { MediaType = "Print" };
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename={1}.pdf;", true ? "attachment" : "inline", "bla"));
            var z = context.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            z = z.Substring(0, z.IndexOf("?", System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
            var b = _pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(z);
            response.OutputStream.Write(b,0,b.Length);
            response.Close();
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException: OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.
```

I've read other SO posts that suggest to use a custom actionresult, so I did, without success.

What is wrong?

Comment: Try to use Response.BinaryWrite

Comment: @dotnetstep I tried, same error.

Comment: Instead of context.HttpContext.Response try HttpContext.Current.Response.

Comment: @dotnetstep also doesn't work :( even in combination with BinaryWrite().

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to create custom ActionResult in this case. Returning PDF data is a very common task and the most sensible way to do it is using the built-in `FileResult`.

Also, your `PdfActionResult` is mixing two concerns here, (**1**) the creation of the PDF data and (**2**) attaching it to the response. The main concern of an `ActionResult` is how to deliver the resource generated by the Action to the client and *not to generate the resource itself*.

Try this instead:

```
public FileResult Index()
{
    var _pdfConverter = new PdfConverter { MediaType = "Print" };
    var url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    var pdfBytes = _pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(url);

    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "bla.pdf");
}
```